# Matching string value associative enums in an array in a case insensitive way

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enums, case-insensitive

How would you alter this code to ensure that both `res1` and `res2` are `true`?

```
enum Type: Equatable {
    case int(Int)
    case string(String)
}

func typesContain(_ type: Type) -> Bool {
    let types: [Type] = [.string("abc"), .string("def")]
    return types.contains(type)
}

let res1 = typesContain(.string("abc")) // true
let res2 = typesContain(.string("ABC")) // false
```

Apologies if an answer already exists, I did search, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define `Equatable` conformance yourself. And for the case of comparing two `string` cases, use `string.caseInsensitiveCompare` instead of the default synthesised implementation, which just uses `==` for the two `String` associated values.

```
enum Type {
    case int(Int)
    case string(String)
}

extension Type: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Type, rhs: Type) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.int(let num), .int(let otherNum)):
            return num == otherNum
        case (.string(let string), .string(let otherString)):
            return string.caseInsensitiveCompare(otherString) == .orderedSame
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @DávidPásztor. I do have something similar to this but it seems really code-heavy. Is there nothing simpler?

Comment: you can use a single `let` for all associated values `case let (.int(num), .int(otherNum)):`

Comment: there's just no decent way around using a switch is there @LeoDabus? I just have to accept this

Comment: @JosephBeuys'Mum This is not "heavy" at all. No reason to avoid a switch

Comment: it's not massively heavy, agreed, but it's a good deal more wordy that a.lowercased() == b.lowercased()

Comment: @JosephBeuys'Mum Btw Swift is a type inferred language `typesContain(.string("abc"))`

Comment: @LeoDabus I know that a single `let` can be used, but I usually prefer writing it out for each associated value (personal preference :) )

Comment: @JosephBeuys'Mum there's no easier way. You just need to write the equatable conformance for your type once and after that it's really easy to use.

Comment: ¯\\(ツ)/¯ so be it